# Python - format dataframe columns as different datatypes

Tags: python, dataframe, format

I have a dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3], 'b':['2017/01/01', '2017/01/02','2016/12/31'], 'c':['aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc'], 'd':[4,5,6]})
```

[image]

I have a list of formatters:

```
formatter = [4.2, '%Y%m%d', None, 8.2]
```

I want to format column a as float '4.2f', column b as strftime('%Y%m'), column c as it is (string, no need to format it), and column d as float '8.2f'. How do I pass this list of formatters to dataframe df?

Thanks,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you switch from a list of formatters to a map based on columns you can use the `style.format` on a dataframe.

Something like

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime

def time_formatter(data):
    return datetime.datetime.strptime(data, "%Y/%m/%d").date().strftime('%Y%m%d')

df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3], 'b':['2017/01/01', '2017/01/02','2016/12/31'], 'c':['aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc'], 'd':[4,5,6]})

formatter = {'a':'{:4.2f}', 'b': time_formatter, 'd':'{:8.2f}'}

df.style.format(formatter)
```

will output

```
    a       b           c   d
0   1.00    20170101    aaa 4.00
1   2.00    20170102    bbb 5.00
2   3.00    20161231    ccc 6.00
```

**Edit:**

There must be a cleaner way, but to actually update the dataframe with the format you could do something like:

```
df['a'] = df['a'].map('{:4.2f}'.format)
df['d'] = df['d'].map('{:8.2f}'.format)
df['b'] = df['b'].map(time_formatter)
```

Or for a more generic (and cryptic) way:

```
formatter = {'a':'{:4.2f}'.format, 'b': time_formatter, 'd':'{:8.2f}'.format}

for f in formatter.items():
    column = f[0]
    df[column] = df[column].map(f[1])
```

Comment: Is there a way that I do NOT have to use df.style? Because I need to export this to .csv or .dat files, using style will not allow me do that. Thanks!